# Irreducible factor decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This is a past exam question.

Decompose each of the following elements as a product of irreducible:

(a) $X^4+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_5[X]$

(b) $X^5+X \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$

(c) $X^5+4X^4-3X^3+X^2+7X+11 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$

---

(a) I run over the value $0$ to $4$, and show this polynomial has no linear factors, but how do I show this polynomial also has no quadratic factor? Do I write down 
$$X^4+2 = (aX^2+bX+c)(a^\prime X^2+b^\prime X+c^\prime)$$
and show there are no such $a,b,c,a^\prime,b^\prime,c^\prime \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ Which is something that I don't want to do in the exam, will take quite a long time.

(b) $X=0,1$ is a root for the polynomial. and after some long divisions. $X^5+X=X(X+1)^4$

(c) $X^5+4X^4-3X^3+X^2+7X+11$ has no linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$. And I know all the irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ with degree $\le$ 3. So I can use long division to see can they divide $X^5+4X^4-3X^3+X^2+7X+11$.

---

And for a more general question, how do I test the irreducibility for a polynomial with degree higher than 3. Since they might have quadratic factor or factor of higher power.

Comment: Concerning (c), it is said that this polynomial is in Q[X], why are you looking for solution in Z2[X]?

Comment: @lisyarus If a polynomial over the integers is reducible, then surely it is reducible over $\mathbb Z_p$. So by the contrapositive, if it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_p$, it also is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$. I'm guessing the OP is thinking about somthing along these lines.

Comment: @SamC Regarding (a) It's not that time consuming, after a little practice you will know by heart what the coefficients of the RHS look like. Also note that you can remove two of them because you can assume both polynomials are monic.

Comment: @lisyarus If I know it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ with p is prime, than it is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Also if the coefficient of the polynomial is co-prime then it is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. This is what I usually do if Eisenstein's criterion does not work.

Comment: @GitGud should one check that the polynomial is irreducible over $Z_p$ for all $p$?

Comment: @lisyarus No, just need to find one prime that work.

Comment: @SamC thanks for clarification :)

Comment: @lisyarus Sorry for the imprecision, the statement should go as follows. For all polynomials $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ and for all primes $p\in \mathbb P$, denote the $\mathbb Z_p$-polynomial whose coefficients are those of $f(x)$ reduced modulo $p$ by $f_p(x)$. The following conditional is true: if $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z$, then for all $p\in P$, $(f_p(x))$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z_p$. *Badly written proof*: If $f=gh$, then $f_p=g_ph_p\square$. So the useful contrapositive becomes *existential*.

Comment: @GitGud thanks a lot, it's pretty clear now.

Comment: @GitGud For (a) how can you assume the two factors are monic? in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ we can have $a a^\prime = 1$ (ie $a=2$ and $a^\prime =3$)

Comment: @SamC Note that in $\left(aX^2+bX+c\right)\left(a^\prime X^2+b^\prime X+c^\prime\right)$ you need to require $a'=a^{-1}$, thus yielding $\left(aX^2+bX+c\right)\left(a^{-1} X^2+b^\prime X+c^\prime\right)$. Now multiply this $1\color{grey}{=aa^{-1}}$ in the following manner: $\left[a^{-1}\left(aX^2+bX+c\right)\right]\left[a\left(a^{-1} X^2+b^\prime X+c^\prime\right)\right]$.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks, that make sense now and by assuming monic polynomial, the question become easy to solve. 

For (b) is there any faster way? What I have done is since there is no linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so $X^5+4X^4-3X^3+X^2+7X+11$ must be decompose into (polynomial of degree 2) * (polynomial of degree 3). The only irreducible polynomial of degree 2 in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ is $X^2+X+1$. So by long division, I show that it is not a factor. Hence $X^5+4X^4-3X^3+X^2+7X+11$ is irreducible in irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X] \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: Faster than what you've done? In this example, I don't think so. I'm assuming you factored it in the following manner: $X^5+X^4=X(X^4+1)=X(X+1)^4$. This is as fast as you can hope to get. If it wasn't such a simple polynomial, you'd need to check it had no linear factors and do it like in a), only this time one factor with degree $3$ and the other with degree $2$.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, really sorry. I am talking about part (c)...

Comment: @SamC What you did seems good. If you're interested you can check the book [Finite Fields and their Applications](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/introduction-finite-fields-and-their-applications-2nd-edition). At the end there are tables of some irreducible polynomials over some finite fields. They list at least all irreducible polynomials of degree $5$ over the first few finite fields.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer can help people who are doing algebra.

(a) $f(X)=X^4+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_5[X]$

$f(0)=2,f(1)=3,f(2)=3,f(3)=3,f(4)=2 \Rightarrow f(X)$ has no linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$.

Hence if $f(X)$ is reducible, then it will have 2 quadratic factors for which they are monic.

$$X^4+2 = (X^2+bX+c)(X^2+b^\prime X+c^\prime)$$

Gives,

$$b = -b^\prime \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space -(1)\\
c+c^\prime+bb^\prime=0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space -(2)\\
b^\prime c+bc^\prime = 0 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space -(3)\\
cc^\prime=2 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space -(4)$$

Sub. $(1)$ into $(3)$, we get $-bc+bc^\prime=0 \Rightarrow b=0$ or $c=c^\prime$

If $b=0$, $(2) \Rightarrow c=-c^\prime$, $(4) \Rightarrow c^2 =2$ (contradiction)

If $c=c^\prime$, $(4) \Rightarrow c^2 =2$ (contradiction)

Therefore, $X^4+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[X]$

(b) $X=0,1$ is a root for the polynomial. and after some long divisions. $X^5+X=X(X+1)^4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$

(c) $f(X)=X^5 + 4 X^4 - 3 X^3 + X^2 + 7 X + 11 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$

$$\bar{f}(X) = X^5+X^3+X^2+X+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$$

$\bar{f}(0)=\bar{f}(1)=1 \Rightarrow \bar{f}(X)$has no linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$.

So, $\bar{f}(X)$ must be decompose into $$\text{(polynomial of degree 2) * (polynomial of degree 3)}$$

There are only one irreducible polynomial of degree 2 in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ which is $X^2+X+1$. By long division, we can show that $X^2+X+1 \nmid \bar{f}(X)$. Hence $\bar{f}(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ also $deg(f(X))=deg(\bar{f}(X))$ (Note: this is same as saying the prime number 2 does not divide the highest order coefficient of $f(X)$), then $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.